# is it possible to authenticate from a website using the fingerprint sensor in Android?

Tags: android, web, fingerprint

I want to make it without building any Android App. 
Is possible to make it using Web only?

Thank you!

Comment: No.  There's no javascript API to access sensors on a device.  You need to write an app for that.